# How to get dynamic parameter from html form in ajax

Tags: node.js, ajax

I have system for liking/unliking posts and I don't want page refresh to occur when user likes post. I want to use ajax to prevent that but don't know how to fetch

```
     <form action="/posts/like/{{post.id}}" method="POST" id="like-form">
           <button type="submit" id="like-button">Like</button>
     </form>
```

How to fetch this {{post.id}} in ajax, I've tried using form.action but that returns whole url i just want id of certain post

Comment: Give it some data attribute like `data-id={{post.id}}` and get it in your ajax function by `this.getAttribute('data-id')` or the best way would be to add an input type hidden and then sending the entire form.data

Comment: Are you using Node as back-end? and are you using templating engine or you built API in Node.js accessing data in front-end?

Comment: @Masood I am using node as back-end and handlebars as templating engine

Answer (score 0):

You're not clear what are you using for the back-end like API built with Node or you're using templating engine with Node, but you can try this on front-end to achieve it.

```
document.querySelector('#like-form').addEventListener('submit', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // this prevents page refresh
    fetch(`/posts/like/${post.id}`, { method: 'POST' });
});
```